# Best rails plugin to save/favorite other users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, favorites

I'm using `acts_as_favorite_updated` on an app to save a number of different models. However, when I try to enable "favoriting" other users, I'm running in to a strange error. (Happy to explain in detail, but basically the routes get f-ed up due to conflicting calls depending on the order of acts_as_favorite and acts_as_favorite_user in the User model.)

Can anyone recommend a decent plugin that will allow me to save/favorite specific models/objects as well as other users?

Answer (score 0):

This should cover you:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top

Answer (score 0):

Try this fork: https://github.com/beno/acts_as_favorite

In your `Gemfile`, add this: `gem 'acts_as_favorite', github: 'beno/acts_as_favorite'`

It provides methods for a model (most likely User) to favor (a.k.a. follow) another model.

For example, `current_user.favor product`

The unit tests should make the usage more clear: https://github.com/beno/acts_as_favorite/blob/master/spec/acts_as_favorite_spec.rb

Alternatively, the `acts_as_follower` gem is under active development.

https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_followable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_followable
  acts_as_follower
end
```

Then issue a `user.follow product`